# How can I complete this proof of the inverse function theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Suppose $f:(a,b) \to (c,d)$ is a differentiable surjection and $f'(x) \neq 0$. It follows from the intermediate value property of $f'$ that $f'$ is monotone, and so $f^{-1}$ exists. I am trying to show that if $y = f(x)$, then $$(f^{-1})'(y) = \frac{1}{f' \circ f^{-1}(y)}.$$

I need to show that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f^{-1}(y + h) - f^{-1}(y)}{h}$ exists. Since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, we can write $$f(x+h) = f(x) + f'(x)h + e(h)$$ where $\frac{e(h)}{h} \to 0$. I want to find a way to relate $y + h = f(x) + h$ and $f(x+h)$. Using the above, we can write
\begin{align*}
f(x+h) &= f(x) + h - h + f'(x)h + e(h) \\ 
&= f(x) + h + (f'(x) - 1)h + e(h) \\ 
&= f(x) + h + E(h) \\
&= y + h + E(h).
\end{align*}
letting $E(h) = (f'(x) - 1)h + e(h)$. Then we can substitute in the differential quotient,
\begin{align*}
\frac{f^{-1}(y + h) - f^{-1}(y)}{h} &= \frac{f^{-1}(y+h) - f^{-1}(y)}{y + h - y} \\ 
&= \frac{f^{-1}(f(x+h) - E(h)) - f^{-1}(f(x))}{f(x+h) - f(x) - E(h)} \\
&= \left(\frac{f(x+h) - f(x) - E(h)}{f^{-1}(f(x+h) - E(h)) - x} \right)^{-1}.
\end{align*}
I know that $E(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$, but $\frac{E(h)}{h} \not\to 0$. I am having trouble showing that the above converges to $\frac{1}{f'(x)}$. Could someone please offer a hint? Thank you!

Comment: Do you know that you can use the chain rule to differentiate $(f^{-1}\circ f)(x) = x$ to get the desired result?  This is much easier than what you are trying to do.

Comment: I don’t believe I can use the chain rule, since I am trying to prove that $f^{-1}$ is differentiable, I can’t assume that.

Comment: Why don't you write $$\frac{f^{-1}(y+k)-f^{-1}(y)}{k}=\frac{h}{f(x+h)-f(x)}$$ and note that by continuity $k\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ (and vice versa). The result follows by taking the limit.

Comment: Here $y=f(x), y+k=f(x+h) $.

Comment: Wouldn’t I need to show that for every $k$ there is an $h$ such that $k = f(x+h) - f(x)$?